# Rebind data in child component when updates (AureliaJS)

Tags: aurelia

I have a component which has a grid-child-component. I pass the data to the grid from the parent:

```
<grid data.bind="data"> </grid>
```

After the data is updated in the parent, I also need to be refresh / rebinded in child. Currently, it is not.

`data` is an object:

```
data: {items: myType[], otherData: number}
```

How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure if this is related, but: `<grid data.bind=data> </grid>` should be - `<grid data.bind="data"></grid>`

Comment: Yeap, thanks for the fix @avrahamcool.  It is just a type here, in my code is fine :)

Comment: Please show how you updatng data and second in a child viewmodel you can have a method `dataChanged(newValue, oldValue)` where you can "refresh" child view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reply myself, as the problem was not related to "rebind" child data. I had a `class.bind="getClassByStatus(item)`, where `item = {status: string, anotherStuff: any}` Well, what actually updates is `item.status` not `item` itself, so, `class.bind` does not observe `status` attribute but `item`, and `item` is not being changed.

So, it was my fault in understand how `class.bind` works.